# Trigger a build on a project which uses a Nuget when the Nuget is updated

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

Is it possible in azure DevOps to trigger a build on a project which uses a Nuget when the Nuget is updated?

Say I have a Nuget called DataAccessorNuget and two projects called DataConsumerA and DataConsumerB. If I make a commit in DataAccessorNuget I want this to automatically publish an updated nuget, and then trigger a build in DataConsumerA and B. In that build I want to update to latest version of DataAccessorNuget, build the DataConsumer and then run whatever tests I have.

Currently I have to so that DataAccessorNuget creates the new Nuget, but I am unsure how to trigger the build in DataConsumer. I see that I can configure DataConsumers pipeline to trigger on builds in an other repository, but ideally I would like this process to be configured automatically so I don’t need to update the build pipeline if I install a new nuget. Also, a change in the repo where the nuget lives does not mean that the nuget has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

> Trigger a build on a project which uses a Nuget when the Nuget is updated

You can try to use the Build completion trigger on the Trigger tab for the build pipelines of project `DataConsumerA` and `DataConsumerB`, like:

[image]

After add the build pipelines of project `DataAccessorNuget`, then when we use the build task `DataAccessorNuget` create a new NuGet package, after build completed, the build pipelines of project `DataConsumerA` and `DataConsumerB` will be triggered. So that we do not need update the build pipeline manually if you have a new nuget.

Hope this helps.